# How to invoke multiple function from string "Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok") C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, backend, razorengine

In server side want do a nested operation with a string. .It will be in dynamic format. I'm trying with razor engine for this. Any ideas..
Eg: "Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok")"
This string mentioned with the functions name.

```
Var input =  "Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok");
FirstPart(int val){
.
.
return result;
}

output : OkYS
```

"Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok")

Mystring.ToUpper() = MYSTRING,

MYSTRING.FirstPart(3) = MYS,

MYS.Replace("M","Ok")= **OkYS**

**Note**: Input will be **dynamic**.

"Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok")"

(or)

"Mystring.ToUpper().Replace("M","Ok")"

(or)

"Mystring.ToLower().FirstPart(3)..

or any..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this case i used **dotLiquid**

Ex:

```
var template = DotLiquid.Template.Parse("Hello {{ username | upcase | trimval"}}")
```

My input is "Hello {{ username | upcase | trimval"}}"

trimval is a function which i called from outside.

```
var rendered = template.Render(Hash.FromAnonymousObject(new { username = username}));
```

When render this i'll get the answer
.If my input (user = "stackF").Assume Trimval return first 5 chars.

Output = STACK

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class StringHelper
{
    public static string Formatter(this string value,bool toUpper, string original ,string toReplace,int startIndex , int endIndex)
    {
       return value.ToUpper().Replace(original ,toReplace).Substring(startIndex,endIndex);     
    }
    public static string Formatter(this string value,bool toUpper, string original ,string toReplace)
    {
       return value.ToUpper().Replace(original ,toReplace);     
    }
    public static string Formatter(this string value,bool toUpper,int startIndex , int endIndex)
    {
       return value.ToUpper().Substring(startIndex,endIndex);     
    }
    public static string Formatter(this string value,int startIndex , int endIndex)
    {
       return value.Substring(startIndex,endIndex);     
    }
    public static string Formatter(this string value, string original ,string toReplace)
    {
       return value.Replace(original ,toReplace);     
    }
}

    Console.WriteLine("test".Formatter(true,"T","TS",0,3)); 
    Console.WriteLine("test".Formatter(true,"T","TS"));
    Console.WriteLine("test".Formatter(true,"T","TS"));
    Console.WriteLine("test".Formatter(0,4));
    Console.WriteLine("test".Formatter("T","TS"));
```

Comment: It will work for this case.
But my input will be dynamic.

"Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok")"
(or)
"Mystring.ToUpper().Replace("M","Ok")"
(or)
"Mystring.ToLower().FirstPart(3).. or any

Comment: Then you should write method overloading for that , or multiple methods with different string methods.

Comment: Its right, But my input will be in string format "Mystring.ToUpper().FirstPart(3).Replace("M","Ok")". !!